# Opencart Elasticsearch - Fatal error: Class 'Monolog\\Logger' not found in

Tags: php, centos, composer-php, opencart

I want to use Opencart Elasticsearch.

So first, setting elasticsearch 6.6.2 by yum, java 1.8 on centos6.9

And I bought Opencart Elasticsearch, Setting is almost finished.

On Opencart extensions page, I have installed by Extension Installer and

Modifications. But when I fill out Extensions/Extensions/module It has

problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1mX.png)

I have installed composer by "monolog/monolog": ">=1.1.0"

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\\Logger' not found in
>   /usr/local/httpd2/htdocs/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ClientBuilder.php
>   on line 145, referer:
>   http://xx/admin/index.php?route=extension/module/wk_elastic&token=hhKuxt3eTkuwjDCI6dX0M6WfdCBTjCyV
>
> PHP Stack trace:, referer:
>   http://xx/admin/index.php?route=extension/module/wk_elastic&token=hhKuxt3eTkuwjDCI6dX0M6WfdCBTjCyV

Exactly my PHP version is 5.5.18 Is that a problem?

My server is a lot of data in db and php. So changing PHP version is very

dangerous. I want another solution without PHP version upgrade.

thanks.

Comment: You should switch php to 7.1 https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php. `5.5`, `5.6` and even `7.0` are outdated. There is no any reasdon to start tne project on outdated version of PHP

Comment: Ok... I will try that. thanks.

Comment: I have update for PHP 7.1, but still I have error below;


 Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\Curl\\CouldNotResolveHostException as array in /usr/local/httpd2/htdocs/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php on line 122

Comment: what are your elasticsearch settings?

Comment: My yml file setting is 
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0 (I tried my IP address, It same error)
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is the setting on Elasticsearch itself. But I am asking for the setting for OpenCartElasticseach plugin settings.

Comment: plugin setting? I didn't setting of OpenCartElasticsearch plugin.
How I could setting that? please teaching to me.

Comment: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=33184&filter_download_id=57&filter_member=webkul    https://image.opencart.com/cache/5c2dec1f126cb-resize-500x500.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> I bought Opencart Elasticsearch

So is this the $199 extension from the developer webkul:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=33184 ?

If so, the answer is simply to ask them for support via the OpenCart ticket system which will ensure that they solve your query adequately (unresponsive developers have their sales income reduced)

Get support here: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=support/contact

Our experience of webkul is that they provide good and responsive support.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion. But I bought $99.. If you have some other solution, please let me know that. thanks.

Comment: Your comment makes absolutely NO sense?

Comment: Yea, I already asked to developer webkul. But he told me I have to ask to OpenCart.. TT

Comment: "he told me I have to ask to OpenCart"
And did you?

Comment: of course.  But OpenCart also I should ask to webkul. So totally I don't know what can I do?

Comment: If you bought the extension from OpenCart.com then you should ask the question here: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=support/contact and this will go in to their ticket system and be answered. This is where extension support questions are answered.